# flask to fastapi sqlalchemy code conversion

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am changing an API created in a flask to FastAPI, but I don't know how to change the following code.

Specifically I want to get guidance on how I can get db defined below in fastapi so that I don't have to change my downstream code which uses db.session.query. In short, I am looking for fastapi version for below code.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to [fastapi-sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/FastAPI-SQLAlchemy/) or use `sqlalchemy` directly. `flask-sqlalchemy` does not seem to be compatible with type `FastAPI`.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the offcial [fastapi guide regarding orm bests practices](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/). Fastapi is not tiedup with any orm or db client so you can implement sqlalchemy same way than flask (with fastapi you can do async db or orm calls wich is nice)

Taken from the doc:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sql_app.db"
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

A [more complexe project](https://github.com/Kludex/fastapi-microservices) that implement async sqlalchemy calls and crud interface